# mclappy: The lapply hack to run on multi-core machines doesn't work for a particular library (pdist) function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

First: The origin of my question is the hack for parallel processing implementation of "lapply" for Windows - by Nathan VanHoudnos

http://edustatistics.org/nathanvan/2014/07/14/implementing-mclapply-on-windows/

My objective was to apply "pdist", the distance function, to calculate "distances" between two matrices.

The original code works just fine - however there is something wrong when I try to use 'pdist' library function.

I also ensured that 'pdist' function name was included in the clusterExport() code.

The error I get is:

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
4 nodes produced errors; first error: C symbol name "Rpdist" not in load table

Reproduced the code here:

```
## Load packages 
require(parallel)
require(pdist)

# Define global variables 
A = rbind(c(3,40,1),c(24,13,2), c(90,8,1));
B = rbind(c(23,4,11),c(13,913,12), c(0.9,0.8,0.1));

## Step 1: Create a cluster of child processes 
cat("\n Step 1: Create a cluster of child processes...."); 
cl <- makeCluster(4)

## Step 2: Load the necessary R package(s)
## N.B. length(cl) is the number of child processes in the cluster 
cat("\n Step 2: Load the necessary R package(s)....");
par.setup <- parLapply (cl, 1:length(cl),
    function(xx) {
        require(pdist) 
})

## Step 3: Distribute the necessary R objects 
cat("\n Step 3: Distribute the necessary R objects....");
clusterExport (cl, c('A', 'B', 'pdist'))

## Step 4: Do the computation
cat("\n Step 4: Do the multi-core computation....\n");
par.Distance <- parLapply (cl, 1:4,
    function(xx) {
       as.matrix(pdist(A, B))            
    })

## Step 5: Remember to stop the cluster!
cat("\n Step 5: Stop the clusters....\n");
stopCluster(cl)

cat("\n Output: "); print(par.Distance);
cat("\n ----------------------------- \n");
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you export libraries using `par.setup`? In the help file of `?clusterExport` library call is explicit at the beginning of the function. I tried this and it returned four 3x3 matrices.

Comment: Hi Roman, Thank you! the par.setup helped me debug my problme and Steve's answer below resolved it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example worked for me, so I suspect that the workers are not able to successfully load the `pdist` package on your machine. The value of `par.setup` should be a list containing four `TRUE` values. If not, you need to resolve that problem, possibly by executing `.libPaths` on the workers just before loading `pdist`.

Also, there's no point in exporting `pdist` to the workers using `clusterExport`. It isn't necessary if you can successfully load the `pdist` package on the workers, and it isn't sufficient since it depends on code in the `pdist` package that doesn't get sent to the workers by `clusterExport`. All it does is to change the error message to the one you're seeing now.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you so much. 

This resolved my problem!